# How to print mysql data in Visual Basic label

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, basic

I am quiet new to mysql and would like to learn more about it. Right now I'm trying to improve and become a bit more comfortable with it by creating my own login form.
It includes a time limit, meaning you can log in for a certain time until your login becomes invalid.
I have already managed this, now I want to read the database with the VB program.
There is a date until someone can login into his account. I want to print this date from the mysql database into a label in vb.net.
I already know how to read text from index pages, but I could hardly find anything for visual basic and mysql to read the data of one value instead of a whole block and display it in the program.
I am very grateful for any help.

A brief summary of the code:

I have a username login.
It reads the local time and compares it with the time in the MySQL database.
If the local time does not exceed the database time you will be logged in. I want to display the time in the database in a label in my program.
Code that I got so far:

```
connection.Open()
Dim command2 As New MySqlCommand("SELECT `id`, `time` FROM `auth` WHERE `id` = @username AND `time` > @time", connection)
command2.Parameters.Add("@username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxUsername.Text
command2.Parameters.Add("@time", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DateTime.Now

Dim adapter2 As New MySqlDataAdapter(command2)
Dim table2 As New DataTable()
adapter2.Fill(table2)

If table2.Rows.Count = 0 Then
   MessageBox.Show("No more time left" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf &")
   connection.Close()
Else
   MessageBox.Show("logged in")
   connection.Close()
   Dim date = [whatever i need here to get the date from the database]
   Label4.Text = "Logged in as " & username & "Expire Date: " & date
```

Comment: You've already got the data from the database. It's in your `DataTable`. What you need to do is learn how to get data out of a `DataTable` so that's what you should be searching the web for. Asking here is not the first option.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

I just added

```
 If table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                Dim s As String = table.Rows(0)("time").ToString()
                MessageBox.Show(s)
 End If
```